# Does mass determine gravity or is it a predetermined quantity

Tags: gravity, astrophysics

If Earth were to gain large enough mass, would it have enough gravitational force to hold the extra mass, or is there a predetermined magnitude of gravitational force for earth due to its location in space-time? 
If not, would that mean that gravity depends on the intermolecular forces holding the mass together in space, which as a result only allow strongly bonded materials to have larger gravitational force?

Comment: Only the amount of mass affects the gravitational field, if the sun shrunk  in size, whilst retaining the same mass, it would still have the same magnitude of gravity as it has now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravitational force is always attractive (and never repulsive) so the extra mass cannot be expelled by gravity. From a classical newtonian point of view the magnitude of the gravitational force between two masses is given by [the following equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation):

$$ \mathbf{F} = -G \frac{m_1m_2}{\left|\mathbf{r_{12}}\right|^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}_{12}}$$

So you can see that there is no predetermined magnitude of the gravitational force. The magnitude depends only on the mass of the objects (i.e. the Earth) itself.

For the second part of your question it is important to realise that the force that binds atoms into molecules is not the gravitational force but the [electromagnetic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism). The former would be to small to bind atoms togheter and can be safely neglected in all situations that don't involve large masses (like the earth).

The intermolecular forces do however have an effect on the density of the materials and thus on the size of an object having a certain mass. However as you can see from the equation, the density doesn't play a role in the size of the gravitational force and only the mass $m$ is important. This means that if you would be able to increase the density of the materials that make up this planet and squeeze it into the size of a tennis ball you would still experience the same gravitational force.

The fact that stars have an upper limit on their masses could cause some confusion. However this stems from the fact that the heavier stars also shine brighter and that any increase in mass would only cause that mass to be blown away by the radiation pressure. This has nothing to do with gravitational force.

Comment: Did I answer your question or would you like me to specify something?

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Could you please accept one of these two answers  for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

In principle there is no upper limit to the size of objects that can be gravitationally bound. In practice the largest gravitationally bound objects are [galaxy superclusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercluster), which have sizes up to around 100 million light-years. The formation of anything bigger than this has been prevented by the expansion of the universe.

From your question I'd guess you are thinking about a solid body and whether the gravity of that body would be able to hold it together. The point of mentioning gravity clusters is that even objects that are mostly empty space can be gravitationally bound, so a solid object certainly can be.

We can see why this is if we consider a sphere with density $\rho$ and radius $r$ then its mass is:

$$ M = \tfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho \tag{1} $$

and its surface gravity is:

$$ g = \frac{GM}{r^2} \tag{2} $$

If we substitute equation (1) for $M$ into equation (2) we get:

$$ g = \tfrac{4}{3}G\pi \rho r $$

So the surface gravity is proportional to $r$. As we increase the radius of the object the gravity at the surface keeps on getting stronger and stronger.